# how to read strings from user till encountering a new-line (Java)?

Tags: java, string, newline

So the problem is that I want to read multiple lines of a string and put them into an ArrayList as long as the user doesn't go to the next line without entering anything.

Here is what the sample input looks like:

```
hello 
I am John
```

here is the code I tried but it didn't work. (The error was: "String index out of range: 0".)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    String temp = input.nextLine();
    if (temp.charAt(0) == '\n') {
        break;
    }
    text.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: `if (temp.isEmpty()) break;`

Comment: Could also use `"".isEqual(temp)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `if (temp.isEmpty())` as `Scanner` will read an empty String.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
while (true) {
    String temp = input.nextLine();
    if (temp.isEmpty()) break;
    text.add(temp);
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest also using `trim`, but I guess a [space] might be considered a valid input :/

Answer (score 1):

`nextLine()` *removes* the line terminator. See the Javadoc.

You should be testing the line for being *empty*.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html

And the method readLine instead of Scanner.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Start input lines, press enter to stop: ");
        try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
          String line;
          for(;;) {
              line = reader.readLine();
              if(null == line || line.length() == 0) 
                  break;
              text.add(line);             
          } 
        }
        System.out.println("Echo: ");
        text.stream().forEach((String str)-> {
            System.out.println(str);
        });
    }
}
```